# What should be the URL for Products page which is independent of Product Categories- Big Commerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

I am customizing my Big commerce Store... I need a products page which is independent of product categories.

I am trying the below URL for products page but it says "Page cannot be found".

**%%GLOBAL_ShopPathNormal%%/products**.

I need the URL to redirect to product page. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

%%GLOBAL_ShopPathNormal%% gives you the store url (non SSL version). The navigation is category based. What you are trying will not work. Maybe, you can hack this - Create a category called "products" and add all the products to it. Then, when you navigate to the URL (storeurl/products), it should list all the products.